# Keycloak 18.0.2 get id_token_hint for logout url by the API call

Tags: jwt, keycloak, openid-connect

Is it possible with Keycloak 18 to get `id_token_hint` value, required for logout url via direct API call to the Keycloak server? If so, could you please show how?

Also, is this safe to keep `id_token_hint` value on the client side, let's say in JWT claim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if I fully understood your question, nonetheless from the [OpenID Connect standard](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html) (section 2.RP-Initiated Logout) one can read:

> This specification defines the following parameters that are used in
> the logout request at the Logout Endpoint:
>
> **id_token_hint** RECOMMENDED. ID Token previously issued by the OP to the
> RP passed to the Logout Endpoint as a hint about the End-User's
> current authenticated session with the Client. This is used as an
> indication of the identity of the End-User that the RP is requesting
> be logged out by the OP.

So you need to pass `id_token_hint=<id_token>`. You get the id token by calling the token endpoint with the `scope=openid`. For example, when a user logs in via browser if you request includes the `scope=openid` you will get (along with the refresh and access tokens) the user id token.

Answer (score 2):

Not the best option, but works, and you dont need **`id_token_hint`**

when start keycloak add the following parameter to the command line:

`kc.sh start  --spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri=true`

Still have to confirm the logout when you call logout page,but you can use redirect_uri in the old way.

`https://keycloak.lvh.me/realms/airports/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth2.lvh.me%2Foauth2%2Fsign_out`

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to skip the logout screen. But it will be removed in future.

You can pass below 2 environment variables to skip the lout consent screen:(Released in v19 Ref:[Release notes](https://www.keycloak.org/2022/09/keycloak-1902-released))

```
- name: "KC_SPI_LOGIN_PROTOCOL_OPENID_CONNECT_LEGACY_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI"
  value: "true"
- name: "KC_SPI_LOGIN_PROTOCOL_OPENID_CONNECT_SUPPRESS_LOGOUT_CONFIRMATION_SCREEN"
  value: "true"
```

Or You can pass then as build options:

```
bin/kc.[sh|bat] --spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-suppress-logout-confirmation-screen=true --spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri=true start
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me to setup applications like Portainer was appending
the two parameters

```
post_logout_redirect_uri=<Login Page>
client_id=<Client Id>
```

to the logout URL of Keycloak like so

```
<Keycloak basepath>/realms/<Realm>/protocol/openid-connect/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=<Login Page Url Encoded>&client_id=<App Client Id>
```

@Source [User anbraten](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/how-is-logout-really-working-and-can-we-bypass-the-logout-confirm-page/15314/5)

Comment: This still redirerects to logout screen ...